# Proof on Dirac measure is a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In the definition given below, there seems to be no restriction on the size of $A$, then it is possible to have more than one $x \in A$, say $x,y \in A$. If that's the case, wouldn't that imply $P(x)+P(y)>1$?

> **Example 1.8.** Let $x\in\Omega$ be fixed. For any $A\in\mathcal{F}$, Let
> $$\delta_x(A) = \begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x\in A,\\0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
> Then, $\delta_x$ is a measure and is called the *Dirac measure*.

Comment: $\delta_x(\{y\}) = 0$ because $x\notin \{y\}$ if $x\neq y$.

Comment: but the definition didn't say anything to imply $A = {x}$?

Comment: What I wrote doesn't imply $A=\{x\}$

Comment: So it is specific to $x$ only. Then doesn't that make it the same thing as indicator function?

Comment: @Sam Indeed $\delta_x(A)=1_A(x)$. The only difference is that the roles of $x$ and $A$ are switched. $\delta_x$ is a function having sets $A$ as arguments (you can call it a measure) and $1_A$ is a function having elements $x$ as arguments.

Comment: @drhab Combined with the accepted answer I got a clear pic now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would not imply that $P(x)+P(y)>1$, because $P(x)$ is not defined. It seems that you're confused by the notation $\delta_x(A)$. Note that the domain of the measure is $\mathcal{F}$, not $\Omega$, so $A$ is the input variable, while $x$ is a parameter specifying which Dirac measure you're talking about. In other words, the Dirac measure with parameter $x$ is defined by saying that the measure of a set is $1$ if it contains $x$ and $0$ if it does not. The reason that there's no restriction on the size of $A$ is that there are measurable sets of arbitrary size.